# Expected '{' after 'if' condition

Tags: swift

I am coding an OS X application with Swift. I thought that it would be the same as on iOS.

So I really have problems with coding that application. But I really have to do this.

So here's my problem. I got this error (in the title) in this code:

```
if email != "" && password != ""
```

Do you know how to do that for an OS X application?

Comment: `if email != "" && password != "" {*/ do something here */}`? Although I'm confused with what you're trying to achieve without the brackets.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thx

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as on iOS.

```
if email != "" && password != "" {
    CODE
}
```

If you don't know how an if statement works feel free do ask.